# Find when a symbol was added to or removed from the Linux kernel

Tags: git, linux-kernel, kernel-module, backwards-compatibility

When writing an out-of-tree Linux kernel module, it's hard to keep up with changes to the kernel. Sometimes a symbol or function is deprecated or removed.

I use ifdeffery to check the kernel version being compiled, and `#define` alternative function accordingly.

To find the correct versions to test against, I use [Elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) to search for the symbol, and manually click on different kernel versions to see at which point the symbol was added to or removed from the kernel.

Is there a way to automate this - i.e. search all kernel versions and return the earliest and latest containing a given symbol?
(It would be amazing if [Elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) would highlight the kernel versions containing the search-for symbol, in the left side panel).

I've found two sources for a Linux kernel ABI tracker, but they both seem defunct:

- [abi-laboratory](https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=timeline&l=linux)
- [ROSA planet](http://wiki.rosalab.com/en/index.php/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3:ROSA_Planet/Linux_Kernel_ABI_Tracker)

Comment: Straightforward is to clone Git repository and use `git log -S ...`, and for first and last commit from the list run `git tag --contains ...`. But better is just to have your module to be part of the tree, which you compile at least each vX.Y-rc1, then you will know that at time. That said, just start from the currently supported version, and then **1.** Rebase, **2.** Compile, **3.** Fix if needed. **4.** Repeat.